# Android Gradle remote scripts using 'apply from:' what does it do

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is about an android project. I have a secure gradle code i'd like to run locally but i want it to be hosted on https server somehwere else.  Thus in my android build.gradle file i have declared something like this:

```
apply from: 'http://server-url/nexus/service/local/get_MY_SCRIPT?locale=en&country=USA
```

My question is what exactly is going to happen here, will this run locally or will the script run from the https servers machine ? What i want is for the remote script commands to run on the local machine where i am calling from. I am doing this in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that command gradle will simply copy the script over and execute everything locally.

By "copy" I mean, it will be in some temporary, in-memory thing, if the script changes on the remote, you can expect that on future executions locally the changes will be reflected.

A good example of that being used can be seen here: https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push

[This script](https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle) is hosted in github.com servers and gets executed by potentially thousands of developers local machines or CI servers.

Comment: i notice on that page its calling apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'   what if i wanted to pass in a property to remote gradle script, can that be done ? lets say i had a property variable called "staging=production" how would i pass that to the remote script ?

Comment: I suggest you to read on the `Readme` for that github project. It shows how to setup properties local to the machines and local to the project. Basically gradle picks `gradle.properties` files from your local machine, from your project tree and the from the module tree and mix them all together.